# Accessing functions across viewModels with knockout?

Tags: knockout.js, durandal

I'm following RN's blog post here about pub/sub synchronization:

http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/using-ko-native-pubsub.html

My application has a 'shell' viewModel with various internal viewModels, one of which being 'folder'.  Within the folder viewmodel, I list folders.

From the shell's menu bar, I need to be able to add another folder.  This is the way I'm achieving it right now:

In shell.js:

```
this.clickedAddFolder = ko.observable(false).publishOn("CLICKED_ADD_FOLDER");
this.addFolder = function () { clickedAddFolder(true); clickedAddFolder(false); };
```

Then in folder.js:

```
var clickedAddFolder = ko.observable().subscribeTo("CLICKED_ADD_FOLDER");
innerModel.addFolder = ko.computed(function() {
                if (clickedAddFolder()) {
                    var folder = new folderViewModel(addFolderDto);
                    innerModel.folders.push(folder);
                    refreshIsotope();
                }
            }).bind(this);
```

The idea is that shell.js will quickly toggle the clicked_add_folder property, which folder.js has subscribed to.  A computed observable detects this change and triggers some function - adding a folder.  Is this a reasonable solution?  I'd like to avoid finding a solution that "works"; I want to learn how to properly achieve this result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using [`ko.postbox`?](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox/) If that is the case, I would think it'd be a bit cleaner if you just dropped the observables and publish/subscribe directly to the topic like so:

```
// shell.js
this.addFolder = function addFolder(e) {
    // 'Add Folder' clicked, publish on the topic
    ko.postbox.publish('CLICKED_ADD_FOLDER', e);
};

//folder.js
ko.postbox.subscribe('CLICKED_ADD_FOLDER', function onClickedAddFolder(e) {
    var folder = new folderViewModel(addFolderDto);
    innerModel.folders.push(folder);
    refreshIsotope();
});
```

Here's a JSFiddle without actually loading postbox, but I basically just ripped out the two necessary functions from postbox: http://jsfiddle.net/QqBhk/

Comment: I'm actually doing this without ko.postbox - I could never get it to work.  I just added the ~10 lines of code to get the publishOn and subscribeTo bindings working.  I did try your approach by installing ko-postbox but ran into an error saying ko had no method "postbox" so I reverted my changes.

Comment: @RobVious What order were you loading the scripts in? Knockout has to be loaded *before* postbox and postbox has to be loaded *before* your code tries to use it. Either way, I'll try to whip up a sample to demonstrate how this can be achieved without postbox.

Comment: @RobVious I just updated with a link to a jsfiddle demonstrating the important bit of the postbox code working. Let me know if I can clarify further.

Comment: JFYI: You might even consider using native Durandal pub/sub http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Leveraging-Publish-Subscribe/ instead of maintaining your own 10 lines of code ;-).